# Proof divergence $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{n+1}{n})^n$

Tags: divergent-series

Proof divergence $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{n+1}{n})^n$

I don't know how to do this problem, maybe a hint or two will help.

Comment: Hint: for all $n \ge 1$, $(\frac{n+1}{n})^n \ge 1$.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that every term is $>1$ is enough to show that it diverges, since the terms do not approach $0$.

(The fact mentioned by حكيم الفيلسوف الضائع in another posted answer here is well worth knowing, but it's overkill for the present question.)

Answer (score 2):

All what you need to know: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{n+1}{n}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n=e.$$

Comment: That's worth knowing, but it's actually a lot more than is needed to answer this question.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I confirm.